# Input from another file

Tags: python

I've got 2 python files. This is the first one:

```
class Downloader():

    def __init__(self):

        baseURL = 'https://example.com'

    def getDownloadLink(self):            

        #linkBase = input("Text: ")

        responseBase = requests.get(linkBase).content
        soupBase = BeautifulSoup(responseBase, 'lxml')
```

And second python file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from firstFile import Downloader

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():

    linkBase = request.form['text']
    #processed_text = text.upper()

    return Downloader().getDownloadLink()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It gives me error:

```
NameError: name 'linkBase' is not defined
```

Is it possible to connect `linkBase` from first file with `linkBase` in second file ?

Comment: declare `global linkBase` in the `getDownloadLink` method

Comment: Always post the full trace back along with an exception message. In your case though, you should pass `linkBase` to `getDownloadLink` as an argument.

Comment: @Dalvenjia This method doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to access a variable that doesn't exist in the scope of your `getDownloadLink` function.

One solution would be to add `linkBase` as an argument:

```
def getDownloadLink(self, linkBase):
    responseBase = requests.get(linkBase).content
    soupBase = BeautifulSoup(responseBase, 'lxml')
```

And then modify your route to send the value to the function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    linkBase = request.form['text']
    return Downloader().getDownloadLink(linkBase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to pass the value as an argument:

```
class Downloader():

    def __init__(self):

        baseURL = 'https://example.com'

    def getDownloadLink(self, linkBase):            

        #linkBase = input("Text: ")

        responseBase = requests.get(linkBase).content
        soupBase = BeautifulSoup(responseBase, 'lxml')
```

Second file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from firstFile import Downloader

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():

    linkBase = request.form['text']
    #processed_text = text.upper()

    return Downloader().getDownloadLink(linkBase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```